# browser re-size causing scroll bar to grow like crazy

Tags: html, css

after going through all my code I found (attached code) is causing my browsers scroll bar to grow in length like crazy when someone changes their browser size x or y axis. Any ideas on why this would be the cause?

the HTML

```
  <div id="boxes">
      <div id="dialog2" class="window"><class="close"/></div><div id="mask">
     </div>
  </div>

  <div id='nav'> 
  <a href="#dialog2" name="modal">CLIENTS</a>
   </div>
```

The CSS

```
#mask {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1000;
        display:block;
      }
#boxes #dialog2 {
        background:url(images/clients_dark1.png)
        no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
        width:1036px;
        height:520px;
        padding:50px 0 20px 25px;
      }
```

Comment: BTW. When referring to an ID in CSS, you only need to use that ID. Use *#dialog2*, not *#boxes #dialog2*.

Comment: #dialog2 is 1061px wide and 590px tall, so the scroll bar is growing to accommodate the size of that box, regardless of the size or amount of content inside of it.